# Why does my pine apple refuse to flower?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, tropical, pineapple

I live in southern California and have this pineapple plant. Its about 5 or 6 years old, so its old enough to have already have flowered by now. I fertilize it when I think it needs it; full sun daily. Water about once a week. What am I doing wrong?

[image]